# Not able to share Facebook/Twitter content from my React next.js website using open graph meta tags

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, next.js, share-open-graph

I have a Next.js application in which I am having trouble sharing content to Facebook and Twitter. I have added the needed open graph meta tags in the head tags of the document and am using React Helmet to change those meta tags dynamically. If I use the inspector and view the elements and look inside the head I can see the open graph meta tags being changed with the correct information. However when I click to share to Facebook or Twitter, I am not seeing any of the open graph data being inserted into the resulting post or tweet.

Can anyone give me any advice on what is causing this and how I can go about fixing it? I thought it was as simple as just adding the correct meta tags and then sharing but I am having a very difficult time with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the Facebook Sharing debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ or tell us the URL you have a problem with.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running this on localhost :(

Comment: That is your problem. How would Facebook scrape your application if no one from the outside can access it.

Comment: Hm so even thought I have some information hard coded into my open graph meta tags, if I try to share content on Twitter or Facebook when I'm running localhost, the open graph data won't populate the post or tweet??

Comment: Doesn't matter. Facebook and Twitter need to be able to scrape your page. So localhost will not work

Comment: Got it. I'm going to push up my current changes to the dev environment and see if it works

Comment: So after running my url through the Facebook sharing debugger I get back message saying "Can't validate SSL Certificate" and it also says I'm missing og meta tag properties which I have in my code in the head tag. Any advice?

Comment: Start with fixing the SSL Cert problem

Answer (score 0):

Expose your localhost app to the world using `ngrok`. It provides a basic `http-https-tcp` tunnel without an authtoken. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok

You can do a global install of the package and then it will proxy your localhost with an HTTPS URL. Use your localhost port (example is port 3000).

```
npm install ngrok -g
ngrok http 3000
```

You should then be able to use the ngrok URL for site testing.